# Reference required for a Moving Average Model

Tags: matlab, references, moving-average

I am looking for reference for a high order MA model. Shall be extremely grateful for a reference.

Comment: what is $ \epsilon $ in this case?

Comment: I would be inclined to say "Past Innovations" assuming that something in the context of the link : [Specify a Regression Model with SARIMA Errors](https://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/specify-regression-model-with-sarima-errors.html) or [Model Seasonal Lag Effects Using Indicator Variables](https://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/estimate-multiplicative-arima-model-using-seasonal-dummies.html) is used. The OP should probably clarify that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any standard time series reference book will do. You could use [Shumway and Stoffe](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/144197864X)r, or my own (free) book [Hyndman and Athanasopoulos](http://www.otexts.org/fpp).

Comment: Thank you for the links.In your ebook https://www.otexts.org/fpp/6/2  the table mentions MA model. Is that the one?Actually I am looking for a sparse MA and AR model where number of non-zero coefficients are less than the zero coefficients. Can you please point out such an Equation?

Comment: No. That is MA smoothing. MA models are discussed in http://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/4

Comment: Thank you Sir for pointing out the difference. I dont have knowledge about econometric and time series. But, in you link I could find uptil MA(3) but not Ar(20) or MA(20) or higher order models. The pages discuss the technicalities and the description of what MA model signifies. I was actually looking for a functional form of a higher order AR and MA process so that I need not generate one randomly from time series as explained in your book. So, is there any Equation for AR and MA higher order models?Thank you

Comment: The very first equation in the section I pointed to you is entirely general. Make $q$ whatever you want it to be.